# Word ranking partial completion

Tags: python, algorithm, haskell

I am not sure how to solve this problem within the constraints.

Shortened problem formulation:

1. "Word" as any sequence of capital letters A-Z (not limited to just "dictionary words").
2. Consider list of permutations of all characters in a word, sorted lexicographically
3. Find a position of original word in such a list
4. Do not generate all possible permutations of a word, since it won't fit in time-memory constraints.
5. Constraints: word length <= 25 characters; memory limit 1Gb, any answer should fit in 64-bit integer

Original problem formulation:

> Consider a "word" as any sequence of capital letters A-Z (not limited to just "dictionary words"). For any word with at least two different letters, there are other words composed of the same letters but in a different order (for instance, STATIONARILY/ANTIROYALIST, which happen to both be dictionary words; for our purposes "AAIILNORSTTY" is also a "word" composed of the same letters as these two). We can then assign a number to every word, based on where it falls in an alphabetically sorted list of all words made up of the same set of letters. One way to do this would be to generate the entire list of words and find the desired one, but this would be slow if the word is long. Write a program which takes a word as a command line argument and prints to standard output its number. Do not use the method above of generating the entire list. Your program should be able to accept any word 25 letters or less in length (possibly with some letters repeated), and should use no more than 1 GB of memory and take no more than 500 milliseconds to run. Any answer we check will fit in a 64-bit integer.

Sample words, with their rank:

```
ABAB = 2 
AAAB = 1 
BAAA = 4 
QUESTION = 24572 
BOOKKEEPER = 10743
```

examples:

```
AAAB - 1
AABA - 2
ABAA - 3
BAAA - 4

AABB - 1
ABAB - 2
ABBA - 3
BAAB - 4
BABA - 5
BBAA - 6
```

I came up with I think is only a partial solution.

Imagine I have the word `JACBZPUC`. I sort the word and get `ABCCJPUZ` This should be rank 1 in the word rank. From `ABCCJPUZ` to the first alphabetical word right before the word starting with `J` I want to find the number of permutations between the 2 words.

ex:

```
for `JACBZPUC`

sorted --> `ABCCJPUZ`

permutations that start with A -> 8!/2!
permutations that start with B -> 8!/2!
permutations that start with C -> 8!/2!
              Add the 3 values -> 60480
```

The other C is disregarded as the permutations would have the same values as the previous C (duplicates)

At this point I have the ranks from `ABCCJPUZ` to the word right before the word that starts with J

```
ABCCJPUZ   rank 1       
...
...         60480 values
...
*HERE*     
JABCCJPUZ  rank 60481      LOCATION A
...
...         
...
JACBZPUC   rank ???        LOCATION B
```

I'm not sure how to get the values between Locations A and B:

Here is my code to find the 60480 values

```
def perm(word):
    return len(set(itertools.permutations(word)))

def swap(word, i, j):
    word = list(word)
    word[i], word[j] = word[j], word[i]
    print word
    return ''.join(word)

def compute(word):
    if ''.join(sorted(word)) == word:
        return 1
    total = 0
    sortedWord = ''.join(sorted(word))
    beforeFirstCharacterSet = set(sortedWord[:sortedWord.index(word[0])])
    print beforeFirstCharacterSet
    for i in beforeFirstCharacterSet:
        total += perm(swap(sortedWord,0,sortedWord.index(i)))
    return total
```

Here is a solution I found online to solve this problem.

> Consider the n-letter word { x1, x2, ... , xn }. My solution is based on the idea that the word number will be the sum of two quantities:
>
> 1. The number of combinations starting with letters lower in the alphabet than x1, and
> 2. how far we are into the the arrangements that start with x1.
>
> The trick is that the second quantity happens to be the word number of the word { x2, ... , xn }. This suggests a recursive implementation.
>
> Getting the first quantity is a little complicated:
>
> 1. Let uniqLowers = { u1, u2, ... , um } = all the unique letters lower than x1
> 2. For each uj, count the number of permutations starting with uj.
> 3. Add all those up.

I think I complete step number 1 but not number 2. I am not sure how to complete this part

Here is the Haskell solution...I don't know Haskell =/ and I am trying to write this program in Python

https://github.com/david-crespo/WordNum/blob/master/comb.hs

Comment: @alfasin i understand and completely agree but I had a lot on my mind and also wanted ti display clearly how far Ive gotten

Comment: That's fine, maybe I'm a bit cranky cause it's 1am sorry for that... g'luck and g'night ;)

Comment: It could also help if instead of copy-pasting problem from wherever you got it (some textbook?) you express it in your own words. It's a bit hard to read.

Comment: If you narrow down where the problem is you're much more likely to receive an answer.

Comment: I believe the problem is reduced to numbering permutations. There's a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) that might give you some insight on how to approach the problem. Search for `numbering permutations` there (I wish wikipedia had anchors for paragraphs).

Comment: @J0HN Thank you for your help. I will be going to sleep right now and continue solving this tomorrow!

Comment: I marked this as duplicate of a question that asks for a way to compute the rank of a string in the set of all of its character permutations. There's also a Python solution there, so I think it answers your question as I understood it perfectly (and it also includes the string BOOKKEEPER, so probably the source is the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of finding the number of prmutations of the letters before the actual first letter is good.But your calculation:

```
for `JACBZPUC`

sorted --> `ABCCJPUZ`

permutations that start with A -> 8!/2!
permutations that start with B -> 8!/2!
permutations that start with C -> 8!/2!
              Add the 3 values -> 60480
```

is wrong. There are only 8!/2! = 20160 permutations of JACBZPUC, so the starting position can't be greater than 60480. In your method, the first letter is fixed, you can only permute the seven following letters. So:

```
permutations that start with A:   7! / 2! ==   2520
permutations that start with B:   7! / 2! ==   2520
permutations that start with C:   7! / 1! ==   5040
                                              -----
                                              10080
```

You don't divide by 2! to find the permutations beginning with C, because the seven remaning letters are unique; there's only one C left.

Here's a Python implementation:

```
def fact(n):
    """factorial of n, n!"""

    f = 1

    while n > 1:
         f *= n
         n -= 1

    return f



def rrank(s):
    """Back-end to rank for 0-based rank of a list permutation"""

    # trivial case
    if len(s) < 2: return 0

    order = s[:]
    order.sort()

    denom = 1

    # account for multiple occurrences of letters
    for i, c in enumerate(order):
        n = 1
        while i + n < len(order) and order[i + n] == c:
            n += 1

        denom *= n

    # starting letters alphabetically before current letter
    pos = order.index(s[0])

    #recurse to list without its head
    return fact(len(s) - 1) * pos / denom + rrank(s[1:])



def rank(s):
    """Determine 1-based rank of string permutation"""

    return rrank(list(s)) + 1



strings = [
    "ABC", "CBA", 
    "ABCD", "BADC", "DCBA", "DCAB", "FRED", 
    "QUESTION", "BOOKKEEPER", "JACBZPUC",
    "AAAB", "AABA", "ABAA", "BAAA"
]

for s in strings:
    print s, rank(s)
```

Comment: You're right! my math was off!

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the solution you have found is also --I think-- what I was about to suggest:

To go from what you call "Location A" to "Location B", you have to find the position of word `ACBZPUC` among its possible permutations.  Consider that a *new* question to your algorithm, with a *new* word that just happens to be *one position shorter* than the original one.

Answer (score 1):

The words in the alphabetical list between JABCCPUZ, which you know the position of, and JACBZPUC, which you want to find the position of, all start with J. Finding the position of JACBZPUC relative to JABCCPUZ, then, is equivalent to finding the relative positions of those two words with the initial J removed, which is the same as the problem you were trying to solve initially but with a word one character shorter.

Repeat that process enough times and you will be left with a word that contains a single character, C. The position of a word with a single character is known to always be 1, so you can then sum that and all of the previous relative positions for an absolute position.